# I need to display a loading image while php is executing queries

Tags: php, javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Display a “loading” page while a php script is executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836663/php-display-a-loading-page-while-a-php-script-is-executing)

Good day all,
 Please i need to display a loading.gif image while php executes queries and launches a page.

I cant seem to be able to access the about blank page in order to place the loading image there. It only appears when the page has totally loaded. Please who can help with a solution

Comment: Call the PHP script with AJAX, put a 'loading' icon in place, and replace the loading icon with the returning HTML from the PHP script.

Comment: Here's a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539305/create-a-spinner-for-my-html-page/11539390#11539390

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#loadingGif").show()
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: { var1:'val1' }
}).done(function(msg) {
    $("#loadinggif").hide();
});
```